# Actionscript Button isn't linking?

Tags: button, actionscript

I'm currently working on a web banner and am having trouble linking buttons to their functions.

Here is my code:

```
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import com.greensock.TimelineLite;
import com.greensock.plugins.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

TweenPlugin.activate([TintPlugin]);

var imageTimeline:TimelineLite;
var speedOfAnimation:Number = .5


var Timeline:TimelineLite = new TimelineLite();


function init():void{
    trace("init working");

    Timeline.to(replay,0,{alpha:0})
    Timeline.to(manwhite,0,{alpha:0})
    Timeline.to(womanwhite,0,{alpha:0})
    Timeline.to(aelogo,0,{alpha:0})
    Timeline.to(sale,0,{alpha:0})   
    Timeline.to(malefront1,0,{alpha:0}) 
    Timeline.to(malefront2,0,{alpha:0}) 
    Timeline.to(maleback,0,{alpha:0})   
    Timeline.to(femfront1,0,{alpha:0})  
    Timeline.to(femfront2,0,{alpha:0})  
    Timeline.to(femback,0,{alpha:0})
    Timeline.to(shopmen,0,{alpha:0})    
    Timeline.to(shopwomen,0,{alpha:0})  
    Timeline.to(bg,2.5,{x:"-200"})
    Timeline.to(bg,2,{x:"-600"})    
    Timeline.to(sale,1,{alpha:1})
    Timeline.to(aelogo,1,{alpha:1})

    TweenLite.to(manwhite, 1, {alpha:1, delay:5.5});
    TweenLite.to(womanwhite, 1, {alpha:1, delay:5.5});
    TweenLite.to(shopmen, 1, {alpha:1, delay:6.5});
    TweenLite.to(shopwomen, 1, {alpha:1, delay:6.5});
    TweenLite.to(malefront2, 1, {alpha:1, delay:6.5});
    TweenLite.to(femfront1, 1, {alpha:1, delay:6.5});
    TweenLite.to(maleback, 1, {alpha:1, delay:7.5});
    TweenLite.to(femback, 1, {alpha:1, delay:7.5});
    TweenLite.to(malefront1, 1, {alpha:1, delay:8.5});
    TweenLite.to(femfront2, 1, {alpha:1, delay:8.5});
    TweenLite.to(replay, 1, {alpha:1, delay:9.5});
    details.shopmen.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shopMenBtn);
}

function shopMenBtn(e:MouseEvent):void{

    // open up URL with new tab
    var myURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.ae.com/web/browse/hp_mens.jsp?catId=mens&navdetail=top:men:p3");
    navigateToURL(myURL, "_blank");
}


init();
```

Help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!